# how to code for layout like the following ?

Tags: android, layout

I want to create the layout like the following picture . I know the layout contains Action Bar , a list . But what is the layout after the list ? 
Any suggestion will be of great help .

[image]

Comment: You can use the toolbar http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html. Since it is a stand alone widget you can place it any where i.e. on the bottom of the page in your case.

Comment: Can you provide code for toolbar in answer ?

Comment: keep your parent Relative and give android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to Footer and give android:layout_below="@id/header" android:layout_above="@id/footer" to Listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are searching for "Split Actionbar"

[image: Split Actionbar Example]

You have to put `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in Activity in Android Manifest.

---

Examples here:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

http://www.sitepoint.com/better-user-interfaces-android-action-bar/